# why does my express not working in the remote host and get 502 error?

Tags: linux, express, nginx

here is my node.js code:

```
// Import builtin NodeJS modules to instantiate the service
const http = require("http");
const port = 4000;

// Import the express module
const express = require("express");

// Instantiate an Express application
const app = express();

// app.get("/", (req, res) => {
//   res.send("Hello from express server.");
// });

// Create a NodeJS HTTPS listener on port 4000 that points to the Express app
// Use a callback function to tell when the server is created.
// http.createServer(app).listen(4000, () => {
//   console.log("server is runing at port 4000");
// });

// Create an try point route for the Express app listening on port 4000.
// This code tells the service to listed to any request coming to the / route.
// Once the request is received, it will display a message "Hello from express server."
app.use(express.static("dist"));
app.get("/hello", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello World!");
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port:${port}`);
});
```

This is working in my localhost on port 4000. But when I run the express server in my remote host 129.226.92.242(public ip) and try to access http://129.226.92.242:4000 or http://129.226.92.242:4000/hello, it's not working and I got 502 error.

My remote host is linux OS and has nginx serve running. I also shut down the fire wall service. here is nginx configs:

```
user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

  }
}
```

So does my nginx server interfere my access my express static server?

Comment: Looks like the firewall on server side is blocking the traffic on port 4000. What happens when you do `curl http://localhost:4000` on your server?

Comment: For reference, this is what I get when I try to connect to your public IP `pansaini@mac ~ % ping 129.226.92.242
PING 129.226.92.242 (129.226.92.242): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 129.226.92.242: icmp_seq=0 ttl=49 time=25.233 ms
64 bytes from 129.226.92.242: icmp_seq=1 ttl=49 time=9.125 ms
^C
--- 129.226.92.242 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 7.655/11.900/25.233/6.707 ms
pansaini@mac ~ % nc -zv 129.226.92.242 4000
nc: connectx to 129.226.92.242 port 4000 (tcp) failed: Connection refused`